# Windows 10 installation create only 1 partition and then can't boot up

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning

I was performing a clean installation of windows 10 using an original msdn iso on a usb stick. Since I am not on a UEFI system I am using mbr partitioning. When I create the primary partition on my empty SSD, I get only the primary one (I always got 2 since one is the primary and one the reserved as expected). After that windows perform his installation and then I cannot boot up this partition. I already tried different iso's and they all gave me the same problem. Thanks in advance for helping out.

[only one partition is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtg7O.jpg)

Comment: What version of Windows did you machine come installed with?

Comment: Have you done the partitioning manually? You should let Windows partition the boot disk, so it can create its own boot and recovery partitions in addition to yours.

Comment: Its a custom built pc. The partitioning was done with the partitioning menu integrated in the installer.

Answer (score 0):

You have done the partitioning manually. This is wrong, even if it was done using
the partitioning menu in the installation itself.

You should redo the installation and delete the partition, leaving the boot disk as
entirely one unallocated space, then let Windows install to that space.

The Windows installer will partition the boot disk, to create its own boot
and recovery partitions in addition to yours.
The size of your partition will be the space that is left after Windows
allocates its partitions (which are rather small).