# how to create a partition after windows10 installation

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I need to create a partition to keep some drivers (preferably at the end of the disk/ssd); I'd shrink the data partition and then created a new one using the UI and the following steps:

```
New simple volume > Next > 2GB > assign letter E > NTFS, name=drivers, quick format >
```

But I get these messages:

1. The operation you selected will convert the selected basic disk(s) to dynamic disk(s). If you convert the disk(s) to dynamic you will not be able to start installed operating systesm from any volume on the disk(s) (except the current boot volume).
2. The selected GPT formatted disk contains a partition which is not of type `PARTITION_BASIC_DATA_GUID` and is both preceeded and followed by a partition of type `PARTITION_BASIC_DATA_GUID`

How to append a partition without loosing data and without these annoying messages? (IMHO, it's really stupid to not be able to create a partition with the tool designed to managed partitions; all the other/hidden partitions were created during windows installation)
[image: Errors]

Comment: Please include a full screenshot of Disk Management.

Comment: Can you run `diskpart` and show the output of `list disk`?

Comment: Is your Windows booting Legacy Mode or UEFI Mode?

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedback! I'd updated the screenshot with full details from Disk Management and the output from the diskpart > list disk. @Ramhound: msinfo32 tells me I'm in BIOS Mode =  Legacy (not UEFI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IMHO, it's really stupid to not be able to create a partition with the tool designed to managed partitions

You cannot create partitions because you have *reached the limit* of partitions. From the screenshot<sup>1</sup> it looks like your disk uses the DOS/MBR partition table format, which only has **four** partition slots in total.

If you want more partitions than that, the fourth slot within the MBR needs to be turned into a special "extended partition" that holds the rest (in the form of "logical" partitions), but this can only be done reliably when that slot is still empty – and on your disk it clearly isn't.

When a primary partition with data is already there, most of the time it's placed immediately adjacent to the preceding partition (i.e. no gap in between), so in order to be transformed into a "logical" partition it would need to be shifted to make place for an EBR that needs to precede every logical partition – and this won't happen here because Disk Management does not support *moving* partitions in general.

So as an alternative, Disk Management offers to convert your disk to the "Microsoft Dynamic Disk" partition table format, which doesn't have such strict limits (but is also officially deprecated and at risk of being removed in some upcoming Windows version).

The second message (which talks about GPT partition types) appears to be bogus, although it *is* correct that there is a partition with different type (the "Recovery" partition) in between two normal partitions. My best guess is that the conversion code (which is from Windows XP era and predates the existence of "Recovery" partitions outright) just hasn't been ever updated to support this situation.

Your options are:

- Ideally, the disk would in fact be converted to the GPT partition table format (which also has no such limits for partition count), but Disk Management does not support such conversion (it only supports re-initializing an empty disk, not a disk with partitions); additionally, when it comes to Windows, GPT partitioning needs to be accompanied with UEFI boot instead of "legacy" BIOS boot, so both the partition table *and* the Windows system partition need to be converted at once.

  If your mainboard is capable of UEFI boot, you could use the built-in `mbr2gpt` tool to convert the disk to GPT and the OS installation to UEFI-boot.
- As a simpler solution (keeping the MBR format), because your "Data" partition is currently near-empty, you could move all its contents manually, *delete* it, then re-create as a **logical** partition rather than primary. This would allow you to create further logical partitions.

---

<sup>1</sup> (There is no "Healthy (EFI System Partition)" anywhere in the list, which would always be present on an UEFI installation; instead there is only "Healthy (System Partition)".)

Comment: I decided to go with the most simple option:
- I'd moved my data and delete the data partition
- I'd created a new partition (which by default, was created as a LOGICAL partition)
- I'd created the other partition for drivers, etc and moved the data there
Everything went well.
This solution/option preserves your/my MBR format, which might not be a solution for other experienced users. Since, in my case, the drive is small I can easily backup it entirely; if you want long term solutions for larger drives I recommend you to use gparted and UEFI (if it can easily be enabled on you hardware)

Comment: I don't remember GParted having the ability to do on-the-fly conversions, actually. (It can initialize a fresh, empty GPT table but that's not what you want here...) Unless they've recently added that feature, you'd need to use either Windows mbr2gpt.exe or Linux gdisk/gptfdisk to convert a disk with data.

Comment: @user1686 - MBR2GPT requires the ability to create a partition which isn’t possible if the disk already has 4 partitions.  It also has specific partition layout requirements. It’s not a very dynamic tool nor does it need to be.

Comment: Wouldn't it just do that *after* the partition table conversion, rather than before?

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to have permission to manage the disk in this computer, let's assume it's yours an not a business one where the IT Dept will get huffy if you try such operations:

You could download a copy of GParted to boot from a USB memory stick, see what it makes of the partition setup and whether it is happy to do what you want (you can setup what you'd like to happen and check it out before hitting the commit button), but do note that some disk driver/configurations (such as Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology)) might cause GParted to advise against making any changes.

The usual caveat applies: Make sure you have a verified backup of anything important before you start, plus check and double check your actions in GParted before committing them to the disk.

https://gparted.org/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot have more than 4 primary partitions on a drive with MBR partition table.

> all the other/hidden partitions were created during windows installation

I try to avoid this by partitioning the drive ahead of time then selecting a single partition during the installation. This makes Windows use 1 partition only instead of 3. Kinda like [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/494684/is-it-possible-to-install-windows-8-in-only-one-partition) suggests. I have been doing this to allow having up to 4 OS installations on a single MBR drive for a few years now, but [some](https://superuser.com/a/1381929/561091) say it's not recommended.